# How to add subfigure in R markdown (bookdown)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I'm trying to add a figure with sub captions in a R bookdown project as follows

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: "subfig"
---
     
```{r  echo=F, out.width = "50%",fig.showtext=TRUE,fig.show='hold',fig.cap="TITULO"}
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
knitr::include_graphics("ts_mult.png") 
knitr::include_graphics("ts_ad.png") 
```
````

and I get the following result

[image]

then I tried to add the subcaptions ("imagen a", "imagen b") as follows

````
```{r  echo=F, out.width = "50%",fig.showtext=TRUE,fig.show='hold',fig.cap="TITULO",fig.subcap=c("imagen a", "imagen b")}
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
knitr::include_graphics("ts_mult.png") 
knitr::include_graphics("ts_ad.png") 
```
````

but that didn't work and it throws the following error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \subfloat 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Tesis_AE.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
```

How can I correctly add the subcaptions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to add `fig.subcap=c("A subtitle","Another subtitle")` in the chunk.

In my environment, at least, `fig.showtext=TRUE` is not necessary and rather this causes an error: `Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'showtext' Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart Execution halted`. That's why I excluded the setting in my answer.

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: "subfig"
    keep_tex: yes
---
     
```{r echo=F, out.width = "50%",fig.show='hold',fig.cap="TITULO", fig.subcap=c("Subtitulo1","Subtitulo2")}
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
knitr::include_graphics("your-path-to/image1.png") 
knitr::include_graphics("your-path-to/image2.png") 
```
````

Session Info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932  LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932    LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2 tools_4.0.2   

> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘2.7.3’
```

[image]

Comment: that's just what I tried but when trying to run the code it throws me the error that I describe in my question *(! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \subfloat )*

Comment: I don't know why I have this error if apparently the code is correct and it has worked for you.

Comment: @User2014 Could you retry with my updated answer (`keep_tex: yes`) and add your tex file to the original question? We need to see whether `subfig` package is really loaded. It's also good to tell your version of R and Pandoc (to do so, run `sessionInfo(); rmarkdown::pandoc_version()` first).

Comment: I already ran in code with the suggested modification but I still get the same error. `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘2.7.3’`

Comment: `> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.2  bookdown_0.20   htmltools_0.5.0
 [4] tools_4.0.2     yaml_2.2.1      rmarkdown_2.3  
 [7] knitr_1.29      xfun_0.15       digest_0.6.25  
[10] rlang_0.4.7     evaluate_0.14`

Comment: Ummm, it's weird since my environment is same as yours and I cannot replicate your error. Did you find `\usepackage{subfig}` in your tex file?

Comment: The package was not in the main tex file, however it was solved, I had to add \usepackage{subfig} in the preamble.tex file, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Happy to hear your success! If you think this answer is worthy, you can click the accept mark!